# Why will my account be blocked?

Tags: support

I was trying asking a question , it says :

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

This is weired since all of my questions are answered and most of them are voted up!

What does it happen ?

Do you think I should ask my question ? or stop asking for a while ? or what to do ?

Comment: How many questions have you deleted?

Comment: @snailplane , None! I didn't delete any question yes as long as I can remember.

Comment: I'm just guessing: is it because two of your questions have been put on hold within a day?

Comment: I'm honestly a little confused though. In the Help Centre link @Nico posted, it states: *... a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts. One or two bad posts will not cause you to be blocked from using the site.* There's no reason, on the face of it, for this warning to be appearing, unless SE has changed the algorithm for displaying it. OP, have you had questions **deleted in any way**? Any such deletions can count against your question block, not just self-deletions.

Comment: @JonathanGarber , No questions were deleted! but one or two were closed. could this be the reason ?

Comment: I shouldn't think so. SE may have changed something though. Your best bet at this point is to hope for a mod/staff response, as they may have more insights into precisely what is going on.

Comment: Note that if this block is invoked, you will be prevented from asking questions, which means that you must write good answers, and contribute to the site in other ways before you'll be permitted to do so again. Your account will still be active, but your ability to ask questions will be suspended.

Answer (score 1):

The exact formula for blocking an account is not public. See [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) on the Help Centre to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's because your last two questions were closed, and perhaps three closed questions in a row might trigger something. I think the warning is intending to tell you:

> Be careful! I hope you are learning from your mistakes.

As far as asking questions goes, I've taken the best guidance I can muster, and put them into these two meta posts:

- [Details, please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)
- [Not just *what*, but *where* is this from?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-that-confuses-you)

I would encourage you to keep asking questions, but do your best to gradually improve your questions as you keep doing so. One (minor) thing you could do is stop putting a blank space before a commas, question marks, and colons. (In English, the convention is to put these punctuation marks immediately after the preceding text – the dash being one exception.)

As for most of your questions being voted up, apparently, one or two upvotes isn't enough to offset five close votes.

Even if a block went into effect, I believe it would only be temporary. [*Nothing ventured, nothing gained*](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning%20of%20nothing%20ventured%20nothing%20gained&ie=utf-8). I'm looking forward to seeing your next question.

Comment: Does this user have any deleted questions? If not, this might be worth an MSE post. Users with only positive score questions shouldn't be anywhere near a Q ban.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName - This user has one deleted question, but not lots of deleted questions.