# Resources for OCR / transcription errors

Tags: discussion

I just closevoted a question asking about the meaning of the highlighted "word" in [*parents seeking to secure a good **Mure** for their children.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/227996/what-is-the-meaning-of-mure)

As a native speaker (with poor eyesight! :) I could easily see that ***Mure*** was some kind of transcription error for ***future***. But I'm fully aware that non-native Anglophones may find this sort of thing much more difficult.

Noting that ELL Meta has dedicated pages for "[approved] resources" (dictionaries, style guides, etc.), I wonder if it might be useful to have a page here with some guidance on how to easily check for the possibility of a transcription error (both to establish whether it's *likely* such an error has occurred, AND in hopes of finding out what the *real* text should be).

So if you think this question might become a useful *resource*, please upvote it. Maybe we should even migrate "transcription error" questions from the main site to Meta, then closevote them against this, I dunno.

And if you can articulate useful *guidance* here for how to recognize and resolve problems of this type, please post anything you've got as a (community Wiki?) Answer.

Comment: I wouldn't wait for the upvotes; I think you should just write a meta question entitled: _How can I spot an OCR error when I find one?_ (or something like that). That meta question would contain the helpful tips you've left here and in the comments under that other question. I think it's an excellent idea and would be a helpful resource.

Comment: I looked at your earlier [Handling scant “What does this mean” questions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/handling-scant-what-does-this-mean-questions) post - which covers some of the same ground, but I think this is different enough to justify a separate post. Maybe I should change my title here to *How can I spot an OCR error when I find one?* I deliberately avoided getting into the *specifics* of "What to do?" myself, thinking it might be better if any suggestions (and phrasings thereof) came from others.

Comment: One post on meta won't prevent future OCR questions from trickling in. But, when that happens, at least we'll be able to point to a very helpful post that everyone can learn from, packed with more information about how learners can recognize these sorts of transcription errors on their own.

Comment: That was all I was really thinking of. It seems a bit "round the houses" to migrate any such questions to Meta, but I can certainly see myself including a link to a Meta question like this (if it can be "prodded into shape") when closevoting questions on the main site that simply turn on transcription errors.